# Automate bgzip and tabix commands

Tags: bash

I have a large amount of files with the extension `.vcf`.

For each of those files I want to apply these commands:

```
bgzip -c file.vcf > file.vcf.gz
tabix -p vcf file.vcf.gz
```

I have been able to automate the first line, but when it comes to the second I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
for i in $(ls); do gzip -c $i  > "${i}.gz"; done
```

The second lines seems not to be working this way:

```
tabix -p vcf *.vcf.gz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do this?

```
for i in *; do gzip -c "$i"  > "${i}.gz"; tabix -p vcf "${i}.gz"; done
```

Notice the proper quoting of the first `$i` and [avoiding `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Thanks. Because I wasn't sure on how to pass the file to the second line. I was using a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
find -name '*.vcf' -exec gzip {} \; -exec tabix -p vcf {}.gz \;
```